# Can Terminator be configured to automatically balance the split windows?

Tags: terminal, terminator

Coming from iTerm on the MacOS side of things, I'm used to having a pretty awesome terminal emulator. Terminator gets you most of the way there, save for one rather annoying behavior.

In iTerm, when you hit the key combo to split the window and create a new terminal, the entire window is balanced so that each split takes the same amount of space.

In Terminator, each split takes up 50% less space than the one before it.

This is best explained with a gif:

[image: Window splits in terminator]

Now, this can be worked around by double clicking the border between the splits, which causes the window to balance itself - but is there a way to have this done automatically?